# Using continue on a generator

Tags: python

I'm trying to skip generated items that do not meet certain conditions using the continue function.

If I simply print `x` I get the full output:

```
>>> w = [1,4,6,10]
>>> w2 = ((2 * x) for x in w)
>>> for x in w2: print x
...
2
8
12
20
```

However, when I try to use `continue` to not print 8 I get a blank space as the output.

```
>>> for x in w2:
...     if x == 8: continue
...     print x
...
>>>
```

I'm trying to get the output of 2, 12, 20 in the second iteration. How do I arrive at the desired output?

Comment: http://codepad.org/032yzZdT

Comment: Your code outputs `2,12,20` without a space  so your problem cannot be replicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generator is different from a list because it generates the elements when they are needed and these elements are not kept in memory the elements. Once you have gone through all the elements, when you try to iterate over them again, the generator will print nothing because it has been already used.

Most likely you have already consumed the generator in the first for-loop, so when you try to iterate over it again, it is empty. Try to `print list(w2)` instead of the loop to check if your elements are there.

### Example

Let's define a function that prints elements from an iterable until a value:

```
def printuntil(iterable, stopval):
    for item in iterable:
       print item
       if item == stopval:
           break
```

Now let's try it two times with a list:

```
>>> vals = [2 * x for x in range(3)]
>>> printuntil(vals, 2)
0
2
>>> printuntil(vals, 4)
0
2
4
```

Everything seems ok, let's do the same with a generator instead:

```
>>> vals = (2 * x for x in range(3))
>>> printuntil(vals, 2)
0
2
>>> printuntil(vals, 4)
4
```

As you can see the number `0` and `2` where already consumed, so the second invocation prints the elements from the first not yet consumed: `4`. So if you want to iterate multiple times an iterable, use a list.

### Duplicate a generator

You could duplicate a generator before using it using [`itertools.tee`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee), so you will have the benefit of non saving the elements in a list.

```
>>> vals = (2 * x for x in range(5))
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> vals, valscopy = tee(vals)
>>> printuntil(vals, 2)
0
2
>>> printuntil(valscopy, 4)
0
2
4
```

This will be memory-efficient but not performance-efficient, since the elements must be generated all the times.

Comment: The "first" and "second" loops are an artifact of my editing the question to try to explain what the OP was meaning (the unclear what you're asking votes) but this is almost certainly what's actually happening as well.

Comment: That means, a generator will not work in this instance, I should have used list instead. I actually wanted to make use of the speed advantage that comes with a generator.

Comment: @enrico.bacis, you are absolutely right, `print list(w2)` gave me an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> w=[1,4,6,10]
>>> w2=((2 * x) for x in w)
>>> for x in w2:
...     print x
... 
2
8
12
20
>>> w2=((2 * x) for x in w)
>>> for x in w2:
...     if x == 8: continue
...     print x
... 
2
12
20
```

Giving the correct results?!

You have to use `w2=((2 * x) for x in w)` every time before for loop (if you are on terminal, as explained by enrico.bacis.); better use a IDE. IDLE will be OK too. If you still want to be command line better make a `function`